# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am just now beginning exploring Angular and am very much a newbie and I am having trouble getting rid of a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.

I have a very simple page for now. What I want to do is basically have a collection of images, and change the style (filter) of each image depending on a color picker in other to colorize said images.

To achieve this, I have an array of "color" objects that contain the following info:

```
export class IColor {
    name: string;
    image: string;
    defaultColor: string;
    currentColor: string;

   constructor(name: string, image: string, defaultColor: string){
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.defaultColor = defaultColor;
    this.currentColor = defaultColor;
   }
}
```

in the component's ts file, I have:

```
import { Component, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { IColor } from './color.model';
import { ColorService } from './color.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'bndl-colors',
  templateUrl: './colors.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./colors.component.css']
})
export class ColorsComponent {
  colors: IColor[];

  constructor(private colorSvc: ColorService){
    this.colors = [
      // new IColor("Background", "screenshot-bg.png", "#000000"),
      // new IColor("List", "screenshot-list.png", "#000000"),
      new IColor("Top (black)", "screenshot-black-test.png", "#000000"),
      new IColor("Bottom (white)", "screenshot-white-test.png", "#ffffff"),
      new IColor("Top Right Menu", "menu-burger.png", "#ffffff"),
      new IColor("Male Model", "male-model.png", "#75dcee"),
      new IColor("Female model", "female-model.png", "#75dcee")
    ]
  }

  getColorClass(color: IColor) {
      return color.image !== this.colors[0].image ? ["imtip"] : [];
  }

  getColorFilter(color: string): string {
    return this.colorSvc.convertColorToFilter(color);
  }
}
```

in the html, i have the following:

```
<div class="imgDiv">
    <img *ngFor="let color of colors" [ngClass]="getColorClass(color)" [ngStyle]="{'filter': getColorFilter(color.currentColor)}" [src]="'../assets/images/' + color.image" />
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div *ngFor="let color of colors">
    <label>{{color.name}} : </label>
    <input type="color" [(ngModel)]="color.currentColor">
</div>
```

Where the method "getColorFilter" calculates the necessary css filter required to replicate the color chosen in the color picker and returns something like

'invert(0%) sepia(0%) saturate(23%) hue-rotate(20deg) brightness(102%) contrast(107%)'. Current value: 'invert(0%) sepia(93%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(271deg) brightness(104%) contrast(106%)'

Error occurs twice when I open my page, and twice again every time that I change one of the color picker issues.

Since I am very new at this and my understanding is somewhat limited, I tried seral things just to see if anything sticks. like switching between [ngStyle] and [style], commenting the second for loop etc. but I'm not really finding a solution.

any help and pointers to how I could fix my issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time, you are going to see that error because you did something in the constructor that you should have done in a lifecycle hook (ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit, etc). I would recommend that ALL arrays that you expect to use, initialize them at least with an empty array.

```js
colors: IColor[] = [];
```

That helps a LOT of the expression changed errors because now you aren't completely overwriting the object type (undefined => []) but instead modifying the contents of the array and Angular is much happier to detect that change.

Now try moving the array definition into onInit

```js
export class ColorsComponent implements OnInit {
...

public ngOnInit() {
   this.colors = [.....]
}
```

I'd also recommend removing all function calls out of your template because they are going to be called dozens of times when change detection runs through.

```
[ngClass]="getColorClass(color)"
[ngStyle]="{'filter': getColorFilter(color.currentColor)}"
```